# Python Libraries Adaptive Neuro-Fuzzy Inference System (ANFIS)

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, pybrain, fuzzy-logic

Are there any libraries that implement ANFIS (Python Libraries Adaptive Neuro-Fuzzy Inference System) in Python? 
Do libraries like PyBrain support it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Recent updates show an ANFIS package available at
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/anfis/0.3.0

Author describes the package state to be in early beta, so be careful on Quality Assurance issues.